# Secure CALayer not shown in screenshots and screen recordings?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have read a blog post some times ago talking about a feature of CALayers in iOS that could be marked as “private” or “secure”, so to not show up in screenshots and screen recordings/sharing.

However I cannot find anything about it and I cannot find again the blog post. Is this feature real? can you point me at some documentation on how to do it?

Comment: "Is this feature real?" No.

Comment: D’oh :) Maybe it was referring to UIViews instead of CALayers. Same answer? :)

Comment: You can observe capturing state (capturedDidChangeNotification) and react accordingly, but that’s only for screen recording / sharing, there’s nothing for screenshots.